# From Naive Bayes to "real percentages"

Tags: naive-bayes, percentage

I am working on a problem which is well suited to be solved with a Naive Bayes classifier:

- I want to know if a certain instance belongs to a certain class.
- I have three attributes that can help decide.
- I have a training set from which I can estimate probabilities for these attributes.

Now for each attribute I have estimated probabilities based on the traing set, which match my intuition. Even the independence assumtion probably largely holds in my case.

But then the classic Naive Bayes approach wants me to multiply the probabilities for the attributes. And although in various tutorials the result of that multiplication is also called a probability, its quite clear that they are not, but rather probability densities.

To give a simple, practical example:

- Attribute 1 estimates a 60% chance of my instance belonging to class
  A.
- Attribute 2 estimates a 60% chance of my instance belonging to
  class A.
- Attribute 3 estimates a 60% chance of my instance belonging
  to class A.

0.6*0.6*0.6 = 0.214, but the probability of my instance belonging to class A is certainly larger than 21.4%.

I have trouble understanding that in the above simple example (three independent attributes, each one indicating with 60% that the instance is of class A), there is no simple way to compute the probability of the instance indeed being of class A.

Can this be somehow achieved? If it is not possible, what is the reason for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the opposite of the situation you have--all attributes giving a 40% chance of belonging to class B. This gives $.4 \times.4\times.4 = .064$.

Since $.214 > .064$, your best guess is class A.

But then, what is the probability of being in class A? You just have to essentially, normalize all class probabilities in terms of the total of the class probabilities. Your total "probability" is $.064 + .214 = .278$.

Divide the two class probabilities by the total probability to get what you're looking for.$$A = \frac{.217}{.278}  = 78\%$$
$$B = \frac{.064}{.278} = 22\%$$

It really is as simple as that. If you want to get more technical I believe there are some issues with thinking of these numbers are "probabilites", but for most purposes this interpretation is just fine. There is a 78% chance your unknown is class A and a a 22% your unknown is class B.